# How do I get the live view on my D7200 to show the results of settings changes?

Tags: nikon, live-view

So I'm new to the Nikon D7200, and I was able to find and fix this issue on another earlier version in the movie settings, but I am unable to figure it out on the D7200.

I use live view a lot to simply make sure I get the right colors and such before I start framing a photo. But on the D7200, it doesn't display these changes. For example, if I'd be taking a photo of a lamp, then I'd  put the camera in live view and change the shutter speed, which in turn would make the image darker/brighter, but live view doesn't seem to show this. The same goes for the aperture, ISO, etc.

How can I make it so that live view will display these changes?

Comment: Related: [How do I preview the look of my frame before taking the shot, on the LCD of my D5100 after altering the settings?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/33689)

Answer (score 5):

Nothing. The Nikon implementation of *Live-View* is not *Exposure-Priority* in photo mode. Inexplicably they actually have an *Exposure-Priority* Live-View for video but not for stills.

This is a major complaint of mine and even the newer cameras such as the D7500 does exactly the same thing. There is no way to change this while both Canon and Sony implement this while Pentax does not. Panasonic, Olympus and Fujifilm have are *sometimes* Exposure-Priority but none of these do it consistently.

Comment: Is this to say that the Live View levels the light to facilitate effective viewing of the scene, but does not change the light on the display to reflect the exposure?

Comment: @mongo - Correct for Nikon camera in question and DSLRs from the same brand. Their Full-Frame mirrorless does a much better job, particularly in Manual exposure but I did not some discrepancies in Auto mode. I'm expected to review their APS-C mirrorless shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Live View exposure Simulation works on Aperture Mode.

Use the Exposure Compensation Button to darken or lighten the image.

You can also increase the iso to increase the shutter speed to limit camera shake.